# System workbench for stm32: fatal error ... no such file or directory

Tags: c, eclipse, arm, stm32

[image]

I'm getting this error the whole day though by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Left Click the file is resolved + the resolver doesn't show it as unresolved. What is interesting too, is the generated compiler line:

> Invoking: MCU GCC Compiler arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb
>   -mfloat-abi=soft -DSTM32F30 -DSTM32F3 -DSTM32 -DSTM32F303VETx -DDEBUG -DUSE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER -DSTM32F303xE -I"D:\Projects\ac6_workspace\emct_display_v2_stdperiph_lib" -I"D:/Projects/ac6_workspace/test_ac6/inc" -I"D:\Projects\ac6_workspace\emct_display_v2_stdperiph_lib\CMSIS\core" -I"D:\Projects\ac6_workspace\emct_display_v2_stdperiph_lib\CMSIS\device"
>   -I"D:\Projects\ac6_workspace\emct_display_v2_stdperiph_lib\StdPeriph_Driver\inc"
>   -I"D:/Projects/ac6_workspace/test_ac6/Display_Driver/UnitTests" -I"D:/Projects/ac6_workspace/test_ac6/CANOpen" -I"D:/Projects/ac6_workspace/test_ac6/MCT_Driver/inc" -I"D:/Projects/ac6_workspace/test_ac6/MCT_Driver/PWM" -I"D:/Projects/ac6_workspace/test_ac6/STMTouch_Driver/inc" -I"D:/Projects/ac6_workspace/test_ac6/Display_Driver/Counter" -I"D:/Projects/ac6_workspace/test_ac6/Display_Driver/graphics" -O0 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -ffunction-sections -c -MMD -MP -MF"src/main.d" -MT"src/main.o" -o "src/main.o" "../src/main.c" In file included from ../src/main.c:28:0:
>   D:/Projects/ac6_workspace/test_ac6/Display_Driver/graphics/oled_graphics.h:23:17:
>   fatal error: gfx.h: No such file or directory

So it looks like Eclipse doesn't care at all what is in the include paths and just generating and running something. Crazy...

What I've tried is:

1. Save All
2. Clean + Build All
3. Restart Eclipse (ac6)
4. Restart the computer
5. Reopen the project

I'm going to try next recreating the project again...

Comment: Nothing interesting. Probably error when variables (configuration ones) are resolved. Remotely not possible to help.

Comment: Everything is possible!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem refering to the following article :
https://mcuoneclipse.com/2012/04/16/symbol-defined-or-not-thats-the-question/

So it was very possible to solve to problem "remotely" if you know how...